# Sorting algorithm for mesh slicing

Tags: c++, sorting, 3d, outlining

I got a problem with the sorting algorithms for a 3D printer software. I get the xyz Data of the slices of a given .stl File as a vector with three columns and n rows, where n is the number of points for each slice.

So the code for the vector looks like this:

```
        x=matrix[n][0];
        y=matrix[n][1];
        z=matrix[n][2];
```

So matrix is my vector containing all coordinates for all points in the mesh.

When I print out the coordinates of the points I get an unsorted list. So the following list shows the points of the first layer/slice of a cube, with the dimensions of 10x10x10mm.

```
X=-5.000000, Y=2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
```

So the result of this is shown in this figur.
[image: Unsorted points]

My first approach was to sort the points, but the result is far away from what I need to have.
[image: sorted]

The sorted list looks like this

```
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=-5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=-5.000000, Y=2.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000 
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
```

The only idea, how I could sort the points is to start in the first quadrant of a Cartesian coordinate system and then move to the following quadrants. As I'm computing layer by layer the z-coodrinate can be ignored. But for this, I don't know how to start the code. Does someone have a hint for me?

What I want to achieve is to sort the list of points in the following way:

```
X=-5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
```

[image]

Comment: you need to know the connectivity of your points, there's no way around that. if you know for example that your points always define a convex set (like your cube), then [finding the convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) of the slice would allow you to restore this information, otherwise you're screwed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the update, this is now fairly trivial. You want to sort the points by `atan2(p1.y,p1.x) < atan2(p2,y, p2,x)`.

Comment: @ MSalters: So could I do something like this:                                            bool compare(vector<double> const& s1, vector<double> const& s2)
{
    if ( s1[0] != s2[0] ) return atan2(s1[1],s1[0]) < atan2(s2[1],s2[0]);
}                                                                                   std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), compare);

Comment: @user3794592: I don't see the reason for that if-statement. Besides, it's missing an else clause.